# Number of normal subgroups

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, finite-groups, normal-subgroups

Let $G$ be the direct product of $k$ copies of isomorphic non-abelian simple groups. How do I prove that $G$ has $2^k$ normal subgroups? What I know so far: Let $G$ be the direct product of two subgroups namely $A$ and $B$ then any normal subgroup of $G$ will be the direct product of interaction with $A$ and $B$ respectively. I'm trying to use Goursat's lemma. I don't know whether the statement of this question is right or not.

Comment: Welcome to math.SE. You'll find that simple "Here's the statement of my question, solve it for me" posts will be poorly received. What is better is for you to add context (with an [edit]): What you understand about the problem, what you've tried so far, *etc.*; something both to show you are part of the learning experience and to help us guide you to the appropriate help. You can consult [this link](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/9959) for further guidance.

Comment: For example, can you prove that it has at least $2^k$ normal subgroups?

Answer (score 2):

Hint: Let $N\triangleleft \prod_{i=1}^n G$, and let $\pi_n$ be the projection onto the $n$th component.

Prove that $\pi_j(N)\triangleleft G$, and so it must be either trivial or the whole thing. Reduce to the case where all projections are surjective. Now consider $N\cap G_i$ (identifying $G_i$ with the subgroup of the product with trivial components in all other coordinates). This is also normal in $G_i$, hence is either trivial or the whole thing.

Prove it must be the whole thing.